# How do I add more fields/entries when a button is selected using xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm creating a mobile app using Xamarin (C# and XAML) for the first time. I would like to add functionality to add another Entry when the user selects the "Add" button.

More specifically, when the button is clicked I want it to create 2 new Entry fields. They are different from each other, but the same 2 appear on the page just above the button. If this isn't possible with XAML and C#, is there a way the button could unhide hidden Entries when clicked?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"is there a way the button could unhide hidden Entries when clicked?"

Yes, just set the `IsVisible` property on the `Entry`.. Simple example:

```
<StackLayout Margin="0,50,0,0">
      <Entry x:Name="entry1" Placeholder="Entry 1..." IsVisible="false" />
      <Entry x:Name="entry2" Placeholder="Entry 2..." IsVisible="false" />
      <Button Text="Add entries" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
 void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.IsVisible = true;
        entry2.IsVisible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this will work

```
<Button Clicked="OnButtonClick" ... />

protected void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
  var entry1 = new Entry() { ... };
  var entry2 = new Entry() { ... };

  myLayout.Children.Add(entry1);
  myLayout.Children.Add(entry2);
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but are you trying to override the `OnButtonClick` method or are you adding a handler to `Click` event of a button?

Comment: it's a click handler, added the XAML

Comment: OK, that's fine. The naming convention is that `On*` methods are the method that raises the event and handlers are typically named after the event itself. So, `OnButtonClick` is the method that raises the event, `ButtonClick` is the name of the event, and `Element_ButtonClick` is name of the handler.